# How to remove diacritics only for uppercase characters in a string

Tags: java, normalization, denormalization, unicode-normalization

I need to remove diacritics from uppercase characters in a string. 
Example : Électronique Caméras => Electronique Caméras (only the É is modified, é in Caméras remains as it is)

I am using the following method, which removes diacritics only from the uppercase letters, but the reconstructed string looks like this - Electronique Came?ras (é is lost). How can I reconstruct the string properly?

```
public static String removeDiacriticsFromUppercaseLetters(String input)
    {
        if (input == null)
              return input;
        String normalized= Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
        newString.append(normalized.charAt(0));

        for (int i=1;i<normalized.length();++i)
        {
            //Check if this diacritic is for an uppercase letter, if yes, skip
            if (Character.isUpperCase(normalized= .charAt(i-1)) && Character.getType(normalized.charAt(i)) == Character.NON_SPACING_MARK){
              continue;
            }
            else{
              newString.append(normalized.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return newString.toString();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static String removeDiacriticsFromUppercaseLetters(String input) 
{ 
    if (input == null) 
        return null; 

    String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 

    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(); 
    boolean checkDiacritics = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < normalized.length(); ++i) 
    { 
        char ch = normalized.charAt(i);

        if (checkDiacritics)
        {
            if (Character.getType(ch) == Character.NON_SPACING_MARK)
                continue;

            checkDiacritics = false;
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
            checkDiacritics = true;

        newString.append(ch); 
    } 

    //return newString.toString(); 
    return Normalizer.normalize(newString.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFC); 
}
```

Comment: Also figured out that it's better to compose the decomposed new string, using NFC, so the last line should be -
return(Normalizer.normalize(newString.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFC));