# Generic way to simplify string, remove diacritics

Tags: unicode, diacritics, iconv

I'm searching for a method to remove [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) and other letter marks in a text and simplify it in a way that it is a good fit for a text search index.

For removing the diacritics, I already found these:

- questions for PHP: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770250/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-text), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635511/remove-diacritics-from-a-string)
- question for Java: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n-n-n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from-unicode-cha), related: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392339/how-to-remove-diacritics-only-for-uppercase-characters-in-a-string)
- question for Bash: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207354/how-to-remove-all-of-the-diacritics-from-a-file)
- questions for .Net: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566793/string-replace-diacritics-in-c-sharp)
- question for Javascript: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939266/javascript-function-to-remove-diacritics)
- question for Python: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

I was wondering about a generic solution, language independent. (Also, this reference list might be useful for some.)

Removing the diacritics works for äöüò, etc. But I also want:

- ø → o
- Я → R
- Ł → L
- ɲ → n
- æ → a (it could also be "ae" but in my case, "a" makes more sense because I also want to replace "ae" by "a")

For example, I want to index the name Røyksopp which sometimes also occurs as Röyksopp just under the simplified name Royksopp. Or KoЯn should be KoRn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ICU magic:

```
echo "ë ö ø Я Ł ɲ æ å ñ 開 당" | uconv -x any-name | perl -wpne 's/ WITH [^}]+//g;' | uconv -x name-any | uconv -x any-latin -t iso-8859-1 -c | uconv -f iso-8859-1 -t ascii -x latin-ascii -c
```

yields

```
e o o A L n ae a n ki dang
```

This uses the cmdline tool uconv, but the same can be done with ICU's Java or C or C++ API, and ICU has bindings for almost any language.

Note Я -> A because that is the correct behavior. What you want is not how Unicode defines that character - blame KoЯn for abusing it.

Comment: I just found out: there are two Яs: Я 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YA' (U+044F) and ᴙ 'LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL REVERSED R' (U+1D19). Maybe I should include several variants in my search index.

Comment: FYI: `uconv` is in the `icu4c` Homebrew package but must be manually linked to /usr/local/bin ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201590/uconv-on-mac-os-x-anywhere))

Comment: This wasn't in the original question, but this fails on inputs containing diacritics without letters, as in `´` (acute accent) and `¨` (umlaut/diaeresis)

Comment: @nloveladyallen, huh, you're right. Luckily, just add -c to the final command and those go away entirely. Will edit answer...

Answer (score 0):

In the Python-specific question, there was one generic solution presented to at least remove the diacritics:

- convert the unicode string to its long normalized form (with a separate character for letters and diacritics)
- remove all the characters whose unicode type is "diacritic"

This doesn't work for ø, though.